# Replacing an element in an OrderedDict?

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

Should I remove item at the index and add item at the index?

Where should I look at to find the source for `OrderedDict` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OrderedDict` uses the position of a value if it is already present;  *if it isn't*, just treats it as a new value and adds it at the end.

This is [**in the documentation**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). If you need to **replace** and maintain order, you'll have to do it manually:

```
od = OrderedDict({i:i for i in range(4)})
# od = OrderedDict([(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)])

# Replace the key and value for key == 0:
d = OrderedDict(('replace','key') if key == 0 else (key, value) for key, value in od.items())
# d = OrderedDict([('replace', 'key'), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)])

# Single value replaces are done easily:
d[1] = 20  # and so on..
```

---

Additionally, at the top of the documentation page you'll see a reference to the file containing, among others, the source for the `OrderedDict` class. It is in **[`collections.py`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py)** and, actually, the [first class defined](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py#l26).

Answer (score 2):

From the Python documentation:

> If a new entry overwrites an existing entry, the original insertion position is left unchanged. Deleting an entry and reinserting it will move it to the end.